# Vizualizing vertex picking of a mesh in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

For fun I am trying to build a miniature Blender using (modern) OpenGL. As part of it I want the user to be able to pick vertices. Each time the user picks a vertex I want the vertex to turn red. My question has nothing to do with finding the intersecting vertex, but rather how one would visualize the picked vertex. 
I have managed to paint the picked triangle (instead of the picked vertex) by using the following in my fragment shader:

```
if(gl_PrimitiveID==intersectingFace)
        color=vec4(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
```

where intersectingFace is a uniform that holds the index of the meshe's intersecting face.

In order to pick a vertex instead of a face I thought of loading a sphere mesh into my scene,scaling it down and translating its center to the position of the intersecting vertex. I was wondering whether there is a simpler solution that this one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in variable that tells you the index of the Vertex, rather than the the primitive: [gl_VertexID](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Built-in_Variable_(GLSL)).

> **gl_VertexID**: the index of the vertex currently being processed. 
> When
>   using non-indexed rendering, it is the effective index of the current
>   vertex (the number of vertices processed + the first​ value). For
>   indexed rendering, it is the index used to fetch this vertex from the
>   buffer.
>
> Note: gl_VertexID will have the base vertex applied to it.

So rather than setting the intersecting face uniform value, like you are doing now, you can do the same with the vertex index and then compare it against `gl_VertexID`.

Comment: Since I am using Triangles as primitives what I do in the code I provided is setting the color of the fragment(aka the triangle) currently processed to red if it matches the intersectingFace. 
How do I set the color of a vertex if the fragment shader outputs the color of a fragment and not the color of a vertex?

Comment: Yep, you said that you had a way to find the selected Vertex right ? Once you know that the selected vertex is the "number 2" of "face number N", then your index is 3*N+2. You would set that as your "indexTarget" and if gl_VertexID == indexTarget then you color it red. This is just an example, the effective index value that you want to use as target would be influenced by whether you are using a GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER and/or applying a basevertex. The link explains this

Comment: As far as I know (and please correct me if I am wrong) OpenGL draws primitives interpolating the color of the primitive's vertices to each pixel inside the primitive. If I did something like:
if(gl_vertexID==1) color=vec3(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f); in the vertex shader I would not get a red painted vertex. I would get a primitive which would be partly be red (since the fragment color interpolates the color of the vertices) and that is not what I am looking for.. 
I disabled interpolation by using: glShadeModel(GL_FLAT); but nothing is painted red.